# iterate a jqlite array

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

Is there cleaner way to iterate over a set of jqlite elements than the following?

```
var els = angular.element(document.getElementById("main").children); // just as an example
for(var i=0, el; el=els[i]; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

I mean, there is nothing wrong with this, I am just surprise that there is no each() or forEach(). And I could not find anything about that on the internet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is `forEach()`

```
angular.forEach(els, function(element){

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice.call(jqResult)` to convert it to a normal `Array`, that has supports `forEach`, `map` and `filter` operations.

See also this [reference from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects).